# Run failed: Unable to establish SSH connection in Azure ML Service Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I am getting `Run failed: Unable to establish SSH connection` error when I trigger my Published Azure ML Pipeline using Azure Function App while the VM is closed. Normally The Azure ML Pipeline should be able to automatically turn the virtual machine on when I trigger it and close the VM when the process done. Otherwise, it doesn't make any sense.

Sometimes I don't get such an error and the pipeline just works perfectly.

Also, the Pipeline works without a problem when I manually start the VM from AzurePortal before trigger the pipeline.

The Published Pipeline uses Azure Data Science Virtual Machine - Ubuntu. I am using username and password to access the VM.

Comment: are you saying that when you trigger a pipeline outside of the function app, it will spin up the DSVM, but it won't inside of the function app? Or that you'd like to have the pipeline trigger also turn on the DSVM?

Comment: @AndersSwanson I trigger the pipeline inside of my function app using REST endpoint but it gives the error cause the VM is not running. I'd like to have the pipeline trigger turn on the DSVM when the function app trigger it and close the DSVM when the process is done.

Comment: The function app is extraneous, and adds unecessary complexity to your question, I think. If you trigger the pipeline with the azureml CLI or SDK, do you get the desired behavior where ML service turns on the DSVM before running the pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree that it would be awesome if ML Service could do this, but fairly certain it isn't supported.

Perhaps you use the function app and the Azure SDK to turnono the DSVM before the pipeline is triggered?

If you're interested in minimizing the time that the VM is running, I highly recommend looking at `AMLCompute`. Provided you can define the desired runtime environment using either Anacondoa or Docker, you can send the code along with the desired environment to AML Compute and it will automatically spin-up the VM(s) you require and spin them down after. You can also use you environment definition to create the same environment on the DSVM if need be.

My team uses AMLCompute heavily. For me, it solves the problem that I think you're asking.